# install of nginx1.12 on amazon linux 2

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am getting following error, when I try to install ngnix on my amazon linux 2

> Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-4597.amzn1.art.x86_64 (atomic)
>              Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
>   Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install.
>   "

I could not find any articles

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2005-December/msg03961.html, but that didnt give much info

Comment: How do you install it? I assume the `dist` part of package name should be `amzn2`, but your package is from `amzn1`.

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2", that is the package available.